# run tasks only if global variable is set to true

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG that looks like this:

dag1:

```
start >> clean >> end
```

Then I have a global Airflow variable **"STATUS"**. Before running the `clean` step, I want to check if the "STATUS" variable is true or not. If it is true, then I want to proceed to the "clean" task. Or else, I want to stay in a waiting state until the global variable **"STATUS"** turns to true.

Something like this:

```
start >> wait_for_dag2 >> clean >> end
```

How can I achieve this?

Alternatively, if waiting is not possible, is there any way to trigger the dag1 whenever the global variable is set to true? Instead of giving a set schedule criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PythonSensor that call a python function that check the variable and return true/false.

Comment: but would that be running continuously then?

Comment: If i understand you correctly then you can create a task that return the variable to false (or sensor that wait) and a new TriggerDagRunOperator to run same dag with wait_for_completion=False. This way you will have all time an active dag

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783629/pythonsensor-always-in-waiting-state

Answer (score 0):

**There are 3 methods you can use:**

1. use TriggerDagRunOperator  as @azs suggested. Though, the problem with this approach is that is kind of contradicts with the "O"(Open to extend close to modify) in the "SOLID" concept.
2. put the variable inside a file and use data-aware escheduling which was introduced in Airflow 2.4. However, its a new functionality at the time of this answer and it may be changed in future.  [data_aware_scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/datasets.html)
3. check the last status of the dag2 ( the previous dag). This is also has a flaw which may accur rarely but can not be excluded completely; and it is what if right after chacking the status the dag starts to run!?:

   `from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
   from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState
   dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id='the_dag_id_of_dag2')
   last_run = dag_runs[-1]
   if last_run.state == DagRunState.SUCCESS:
   print('the dag run was successfull!')
   else:
   print('the dag state is -->: ', last_run.state)`

**After all it depends on you and your business constraint to choose among these methods.**

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783629/pythonsensor-always-in-waiting-state